# Why does this array have object key value pairs?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I didn't even know that this was possible, what is this? I tried running this on chrome and firefox, and got the same result:

[image]

I'm sending a 100 item array from the server, but when it gets to the client, this happens.

I tried accessing the item at index 100, and got undefined as response.
I also tried slicing it to the first 100 items, but the rest of the key pairs remain there.

I can't try to access the values by key because they are random every time. If that's of any value.

Comment: Can you show the code that produces this array?

Comment: An array of size 100, have only keys from 0 to 99, I am seeing in your result you have 99 as max index array.

Comment: @ggorlen it's literally just that. A plain 2d array.

Comment: @OmarAlvarado I tried accessing the array at 100 to see if I can get a response. And I can't, so that's good. It means the other values have to be accessed by key, I suppose.

Comment: The image doesn't show a "plain 2d array", it shows an array with properties added to it. That's very unusual and likely not going to happen unless you write code that explicitly (and probably inadvertently) set these properties. Likely, there is some code that mistakes the array as an object. But this is all speculation without a [mcve] showing how the array was created and all of the relevant code where properties were added. So, the answer to "why are the keys there?" is "because someone added them, likely by mistake".

Comment: You are right! It totally slipped my mind but those numbers on the left are actually the property names, not line numbers, as I thought. I looked further into the code and there was some code that took the array parameter as an object and not like an array, just like you said. That fixed my issue, thanks. I'd love to give you credit but it's a comment, not an Answer to the post. What should I do?

Comment: If you try to assign a non-integer index to an array, it will be treated as a property name, not an array index.  An array is a sub-class of Object so it can have regular properties too.

Answer (score 1):

Since an array is also an object, you can add arbitrary properties to it.  Run this code then look in your browser console (not the console inside this post).

```js
const array = ['11034.61000000', '0.30200000'];

array['10987'] = 0.009101;
array['11024.05'] = 0.001998;
array['11026.96'] = 0.001;
array['11026.59'] = 1.5;

console.log(array);
console.log(Object.keys(array));
```

`Object.keys(array)` will show you every property of the array, even the random ones.